# jquery actions visible for others

Tags: jquery

I made a website where users can post texts and get to see them, like the Twitter status. But now I want that other visitors from other ips of my website also get to see that posts. So not only the user on the website self, but also other users can see the posts?

Greetz Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want other users to be able to see the posts, you'll have to save them on your server - you can't do it with jQuery, because jQuery works in your users' browser.

To save them, you'll need a program running on your server, that can interpret your commands, when you tell it to save a post. PHP is a good language to start with, if you want to implement this.